# Power BI Slicers. Remove value from offset slicer based on selection in reference slicer

Tags: powerbi, reference, offset, slicers

We are comparing performance data of a reference item with offset items.
Therefore we have two slicers, one to pick up the reference item and one to pick up the offset item. (They are supported by two identical views, but one is used for the reference slicer, and the other is for the offset slicer, since there are global filters as well, which shouldn't affect the offset values only the reference slicer.)

How can I remove the element picked up in the reference slicer not to be shown in the offset slicer? Obviously we don't want to compare an element with itself, neither want that element to be selected among the  offset items.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Try to upload a copy of the dataset and PBIX

Comment: Thanks Francesco. Meanwhile I have found the answer in a youtube video.